# Unable to create share dialog using facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a simple app, in which I am using facebook sdk to get user info. I am trying to share content by using `ShareLinkContent.Builder` but I am receving error:

```
onError:
 {FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: 100, facebookErrorType: null, message: The parameter 'href' or 'media' is required}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
 CallbackManager callbackManager;
 ShareDialog shareDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

     shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "cancel");
        }
    });
     createPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent.Builder post = new ShareLinkContent.Builder();
                post = post.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(""));
                post.setContentTitle("");
                shareDialog.show(MainActivity.this, post.build());
            }
        }
    });
  }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode,     final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

What happens is that, dialog does not appear and I get the above error in logcat.

UPDATE:

**What I want:**

Is it possible to use `ShareLinkContent.Builder` with a null `setContentUrl`, I just want my user to share his text not a link or something else. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see `href` or `media` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Did you try with a valid uri ?

Comment: @GiuseppeLabanca i tried with valid uri, and the result is it loads endlessly! Is there any way to not put uri?

Comment: Do you have network permissions?

Comment: Yes i have network permissions

Comment: @CBroe can't i got empty?

Comment: @Michal_196 What do you need to share? If you need to share a "Link" you must put an uri.

Comment: No i don't want to share "link" just user's thought on my application.

Comment: Is there any fix to this issue?